# Execute multiple mysql satement in shell script parallelly using GNU Parallel

Tags: mysql, shell

I have a shell script that has multiple load data statements that loads data from csv files into tables in MySQL. How to make use of GNU Parallel to execute these statements in parallel?

My shell script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql --defaults-extra-file=config.cnf -e "SELECT *
FROM table1
INTO OUTFILE '$path/table1.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';"

mysql --defaults-extra-file=config.cnf -e "SELECT *
FROM table2
INTO OUTFILE '$path/table2.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';"

mysql --defaults-extra-file=config.cnf -e "SELECT *
FROM table3
INTO OUTFILE '$path/table3.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';"

echo "END of script"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
doit() {
  table="$1"
  tablepath="$2"
  mysql --defaults-extra-file=config.cnf -e "SELECT *
    FROM $table
    INTO OUTFILE '$tablepath' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';"
}
export -f doit
parallel doit {/.} {} ::: path/table*.csv
```